# When do errors stop calculations?

Tags: plotting, precision-and-accuracy

When plotting `Plot[Exp[-1/(1 - (x + 10)^2)], {x, -11, -10}]`, I get the following warning

[image]

but the `Plot` follows. However, if I define a piecewise function and try to plot it, I get the same warning and no Plot is produced.

```
Plot[Piecewise[{{Exp[-1/(1 - (x + 10)^2)], {x <= -10}}, {Exp[-1], {-10 < x < 
  10}}}], {x, -11, 10}]
```

Why is this happening? The documentation of the error suggests this can be avoided by adjusting the precision. But I'm more interested in understanding why the error stops the output in one case and not in the other.

Comment: The syntax of `Piecewise` is wrong, there should be no `{}` around the condition i.e. it should be `Plot[Piecewise[{{Exp[-1/(1 - (x + 10)^2)], x <= -10}, {Exp[-1], -10 < x < 10}}], {x, -11,
   10}]`

Comment: Silly me, Thanks @xzczd